# Getopts - command with multiple options

Tags: command-line, unix, script

I have a command script i'm making and wondering how do i go about combining multiple options

the general usage of the command is as follows:

Usage: myCommand [-fpr] [-n count] [-s size] [-u user] [-d directory]

My question refers to the [-fpr] option. If the user types myCommand -fpr or myCommand -fp how do I combine/concatenate the options together if it's in a while loop?

```
while getopts "fpr" opt; do
    case $opt in
    f)
        echo `-l`
        echo "-f was triggered!" >&2
        ;;
    p)
            echo `-h`
        echo "-p was triggered!" >&2
        ;;
    r)
        echo "-r was triggered!" >&2
        ;;

    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG\n" >&2
        usage
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I don't understand your actual question. But `echo \`-h\`` does not make sense as it tries to execute `-h` and then echo it's output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to figure out how to handle `-fpr` the same as `-f -p -r`. In that case, `getopts` does this for you.

If you want to use the "long option" `-fpr` and not threat it identical to `-f -p -r`, then you need to abandon `getopts`, and look to for example `getopt` (note the lack of the `s` at the end), which supports long options. See e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt for details.